Webservice in Docker Container inside VM not accessible despite port-forwarding
I am running a Quarkus RESTful Webservice inside a Docker container which runs in a VM (Ubuntu 22.04). I have an Angular frontend (named frontend), a Quarkus backend (named quarkus), an authorization server (named keycloak-w) and a MySQL-DB (named mysql-kc), that is used by Keycloak as a persistent storage. The goal is to only forward the ports of the frontend-service which is deployed via nginx. However, for testing purposes I exposed the 8080 port for the quarkus webservice to check if I can access it. Unfortunately I am not able to do so. So, first here is the docker-compose.yml, the setup works on my local machine:
version: '3.9'

services:

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ../
      network: host
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_URL: 'http://keycloak-w:8080'
      KEYCLOAK_REALM: code2uml
      KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID: code2uml
      BACKEND: 'http://quarkus:8080'
      DOMAIN: 'my.domain'
    volumes:
      - ./imports/java/:/opt/jboss/container/java/run/
    networks:
      - keycloak-and-mysql-network

  quarkus:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      network: host
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK: keycloak-w
    volumes:
      - ./imports/java/:/opt/jboss/container/java/run/
    networks:
      - keycloak-and-mysql-network

  mysql-kc:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    ports:
      - 3366:3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      # The user, password and database that Keycloak
      # is going to create and use
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: keycloak_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak_db
      # Self-Explanatory
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping -P 3306 -proot_password | grep 'mysqld is alive' || exit 1" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - keycloak-and-mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
#      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - keycloak-and-mysql-network

  keycloak-w:
    image: keycloak/keycloak:22.0.5
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - start-dev
      - --import-realm
    environment:
      # User and password for the Administration Console
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: timmyOTool
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: myPassword
      KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /opt/keycloak/data/import/code2uml-realm.json
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: 'false'
      KC_DB: mysql
      KC_DB_URL: 'jdbc:mysql://mysql-kc:3306/keycloak_db'
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak_user
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak_password
      KC_Hostname: localhost
      KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD: secret
      DB: keycloak_db
      DB_URL_HOST: mysql-kc
      DB_SCHEMA: keycloak
      DB_USERNAME: keycloak_user
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloak_password
      DB_PORT: 3306
    depends_on:
      mysql-kc:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./imports:/opt/keycloak/data/import
      - ./export:/export
    networks:
      - keycloak-and-mysql-network

networks:
  keycloak-and-mysql-network:

volumes:
  keycloak-and-mysql-volume:

So I checked the following on the VM (via Putty and SSH): If I try to do a curl localhost:8080 it takes some time and I receive curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer. In the file /etc/hosts there is a mapping from 127.0.0.1 to localhost. I also found this question (docker-compose up not forwarding port), so I took a look inside the logs of the quarkus webservice: It tells me, that it is listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080. So it seems not to use localhost in the application code.
2024-09-16 15:19:38,712 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) my-service on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.11.2) started in 6.259s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080

When I remove the networks part in he docker-compose.yml (under quarkus) and replace it with network_mode: host everything works fine and I am even able to connect to the webservice from my local machine (curl my.domain:8080 works and I receive some Quarkus-specific html). However, that is not what I want. In the end I want to do no port-forwarding at all (except for the frontend-service which is my reverse proxy), this is just for testing purposes.
On the other hand the setup works fine on my local machine and if I execute the above curl localhost:8080 I receive some Quarkus-specific html.
Does anybody have an idea why the service is not accessible, although it is up and running (at least on the VM) and the port is forwarded? Do I need maybe some kind of network bridge? Any help is kindly appreciated.
UPDATE: I compared the network-settings (by running docker inspect container_id) of both my locally running WS and the corresponding settings on the VM and I realized the following differences:
Local:
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "5b43932cc258003afdef4d9403f53beb0ff5365e0285ca233546895d10105a67",
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/5b43932cc258",
    "Ports": {
        "8080/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "8080"
            }
        ]
    },

VM:
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "720e610735d12a295499e70146256fdcb2b1c9320f8974794323fddaf6ade942",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "8080/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "8080"
            },
            {
                "HostIp": "::",
                "HostPort": "8080"
            }
        ]
    },

Is the problem maybe somehow related to the usage of IPv6-adresses?

So to clarify, you can't access any container when running it inside the VM (without network_mode: host)? Sounds like the issue is the VM, not your docker setup.

Yes, that is correct

I was finally able to find a solution to my problem (original link can be found here). In case the above links will be removed in the future, I executed the following steps on my VM:

Modify the file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml and add en in front of the *:

network:
  ethernets:
    all:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      match:
        name: 'en*'
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2


Apply the configuration and restart network:

netplan apply
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd

#Docker needs to be restarted to request a new ip
sudo systemctl restart docker

Explanation: Ubuntu 22.04 uses netplan to adress ip via DHCP. The change in the above configuration file forces netplan to use DHCP only on interface en* and the docker interface is docker0.
